# To make loading Image to the center of the document

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code to browse and load the image from the local machine.

```
<input type='file' id="fileUpload" />
<canvas id="canvas" "></canvas>
```

Here is the JavaScript for this

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;


function readImage() {
  if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
      var FR= new FileReader();
      FR.onload = function(e) {
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function() {
         context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
         };
         img.src = e.target.result;
         };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

How can i make the loading image to the Center of the Screen?

Comment: Just a tip: do `src = URL.createObjectURl(file)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need horizontal and vertical center, replace this line:

```
 context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

with this:

```
 context.drawImage(img, (canvas.width - this.width) / 2,(canvas.height  - this.height) / 2);
```

Since your canvas is 100% of scren width/height, you can use this simple centralizing method.

Also, you can add this in your css:

```
#canvas {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;

}
input {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  left:10px;
}
```

to remove scrollbars (because input takes some height, img will not be perfectly centered).

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/uanzegLf/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display a image when you send the form or a input change, you can use this:

> document.getElementById("elementID").style.visibility = "hidden"; **to hide a element and**
>
> document.getElementById("elementID").style.visibility = "visible"; **to show a element**

you can create a function to hide the first element and then show the "loading image element" and then assing it to the input on the onchange property

`<input type="file" onChange="loadingImage();">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT using HTML5, use the `<center>` tag.

If you are, use css and use `text-align: center`